# .htaccess URL rewrite not working (except 1 line)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently Implementing .amp pages so I copied the url rewrite rules on the same htaccess file. Except one, all is working..

```
NORMAL version
    RewriteRule ^tours/reviews$ reviews.php [QSA,L] **works**
    RewriteRule ^tours/reviews-(.*)$ reviews.php?git=$1 [QSA,L] **works**

AMP Version
    RewriteRule ^tours/reviews.amp$ reviews.amp.php [QSA,L] **works**
    RewriteRule ^tours/reviews-(.*).amp$ reviews.amp.php?git=$1 [QSA,L] **does not work**
```

Tried escaping - or .  did not solve it.

When I get rid of "-" in the URL, it works.. I am confused..
Any ideas ?

Comment: All 4 rules are in the file, with `reviews-(.*)$` before `reviews-(.*).amp$`?

Comment: I think @wrwrwr is implying that it looks like your second rule is too greedy so the 4th will never match. Adding a negative look-behind assertion like `(?<!\.amp)` right before the `$` on the second rule would prevent that.

Comment: Or, easier, place version AMP before the other.

Comment: Thank you @Walf
moving the 4th line before the 2nd did solve. Also adding the extra bit resolves it.
Currently line 2 is;
RewriteRule ^tours/reviews-(.*)(?<!\.amp)$ reviews.php?git=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @Croises of course 